# How to completely disable all exit warning/confirm messages with userscript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am using chrome in an isolated environment to scan malicious websites to analyze their data to create blacklists. This process is completely automated by userscripts and browser extensions.

The problem is that some sites are able to show an exit dialog on `beforeunload` or `unload` (I will refer to these as `events`).

I already override these `events`, but when the site override my override again, the whole process stops. I mean they can redefine the `events` with AJAX calls, obfuscated scripts, evals, etc.

Is there any way to get rid of these messages, or protect my override?
Maybe unsafeWindow would handle this, but I would avoid to use it in this nasty environment.

**EDIT** - Currently I use this code in my userscript:

```
location.href = "javascript:(" + function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    window.onunload = null;
} + ")()";

setInterval(function(){
    location.href = "javascript:(" + function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        window.onunload = null;
    } + ")()";
}, 3000);
```

Comment: 1. Add the code you're using now to block those events into the question. 2. Basically I think you'll need to use every imaginable trick like e.g. overriding the events in `unsafeWindow`, processing `unsafeWindow.jQuery._data(unsafeWindow.window, "events")` when jQuery is defined, etc.

Comment: The override in a while(true){} would work in almost any cases, but I don't want to use too much resources.

Comment: I think location hack doesn't work in modern browsers or will stop working in a few months when the new versions will be out of beta.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using some older version of Chrome, because this behavior has been removed since Chrome 51 [[Custom messages in onbeforeunload dialogs (removed)](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480)].

The problem relies on `onBeforeUnload` event. Browsers (*Chrome and Firefox at least*) have disabled messages from inside `onUnload` event. The pages you're trying to hook your timer and change the `window.onbeforeunload = null` are probably also using a timer to set the same event with a very small interval value, even 1 millisecond, so it will be really difficult to override that event when having an other timer with a smaller interval setting it again and again. My approach is to kill all the timers inside the script and it worked for me with Chrome 49 I have in an old VM.

```
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var killId = setTimeout(function() {
        for(var i = killId; i > 0; i--) clearInterval(i);
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        // If you don't use interval timers then disable setInterval function
        // else you can store the function to a variable before
        // you set it to an empty function;
        // Same goes for setTimeout
        setInterval = function() {};
    }, 10);

})();
```

For a refference test page, I used this simple javascript that runs an interval timer to set the `window.onbeforeunload` every millisecond:

```
function goodbye(e) {
    var msg = 'You sure you want to leave?';
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    if(e) {
        //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = msg; //This is displayed on the dialog

        //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } else
        return msg;
}

// Set a timer to hook `onBeforeUnload` event every millisecond
setInterval(function() { window.onbeforeunload = goodbye; }, 1);
```

Some pages may use `setTimeout()` instead `setInterval()` so you may want to also disable `setTimeout = function() {}` function.

Comment: These events are still firing in the latest Chrome, version 59.0.3071.115 (64bit) on windows, for example.  An example of a site that uses them is Reddit -- simply click on a reply, enter some text, then close the window or tab and you will see the leave confirmation popup.

Comment: @alzee the `onBeforeUnload` event only fires if there is a form and the user has filled it with some data. You just said it in your comment; you have to **type in some text** for the popup to appear otherwise it won't popup.  It won't fire anymore if you just set a listener to it in a page without a form and without data populated by the user. Can you provide one link that this popup message shows up by it's own on close **WITHOUT** the user has filled some data to a form?

Comment: @alzee if the script is only for you and you need to disable those popups, then you should try and start Chrome with the option `-disable-prompt-on-repost`. That will disable those messages. I don't think you can disable it programmatically by javascript. BTW, the code this `Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey` script uses, is posted from **2011** and for `Greasemonkey/Firefox` http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=10347053#p10347053

Comment: The `disable-prompt-on-repost` flag is for something different -- preventing form submission from happening on a refresh.  That flag isn't going to help here.  Here is an example of one I would want the script to fix: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload

Comment: FYI the link you reference is a bugfix that simply prevents websites from displaying custom text in the popup, *it does not prevent the popup from showing in the first place* which is what I and the original question asker want to happen.

Comment: @alzee FYI the link I reference has the code that the author of this question here got the sample code of... and the suggestion is to use **Greasemonkey** as the author of this question here has tagged for... And the link you re referring **DOES NOT** popup a message when you hit the **X** on the tab **WHEN THE PAGE LOADS**, but **ONLY** if you try to click on the page link and after some interaction. And yes, my code works for that case. Did you try my code and does not work for you? I have a complete example that shows it's working and I will post it here if you say it does not.

Comment: Christos, yes I tried it, no it *does not work*.  I am using this test html: https://pastebin.com/nZ4s0K3e which is a copy of the w3c example with this greasemonkey script (yours) in the *latest* version of chrome: https://pastebin.com/hpXBv9AU  If you navigate away or press F5, you get the popup.

Comment: Actually that was entirely my mistake.  I forgot that these scripts do not work with file:// access.  I'll give you the bounty, it is indeed working when I move the HTML file to an actual webserver.  Thanks!

Comment: @alzee You're welcome. I was ready to record a gif screen capture just to show you that it's working for me. It's nice you got this working on your side. Thanks for the bounty.

Comment: Eh I granted the bounty but you know what?  It's only working on that test page, it still does not work on a site where you have entered some text -- e.g. reddit.  The popup still happens there.  Bleh.  I'll make another bounty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151549/discussion-between-christos-lytras-and-alzee).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'onunload', { 
    value: null,
    configurable: false
});

window.onunload = 1;

window.onunload;
// null
```

`configurable` is set to false which means the property can't be changed.