# Userscript to disable window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I'm trying to create a userscript that disables window.onbeforeunload on all pages. I've tried inserting the following script at document_start:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'onbeforeunload', {
    'value': null
});
```

This way window.onbeforeunload can't be set by any other script on the page. This works fine, except for when the page contains another script that tries to set window.onbeforeunload with strict mode enabled, for example:

```
'use strict';
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return true;
};
//Script execution stops after this
console.log(window.onbeforeunload);
```

This causes an exception to be thrown and will stop script execution entirely, which seems a bit harsh.

Is there any way to prevent window.onbeforeunload from being set, but not so that the other scripts on the page will stop executing entirely when strict mode is enabled?

Thanks!

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958606/how-to-completely-disable-all-exit-warning-confirm-messages-with-userscript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a setter property instead, and just discard the value.

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'onbeforeunload', {
    'set': function() {}
});

(function() {
'use strict';
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return true;
};
console.log(window.onbeforeunload);
})();
```

Then when something tries to set it in strict mode, it just gets discarded rather than throwing an error.

If you want to make it extra-bullet-proof, you can override both the getter and the setter, to return a function you stored in a variable instead.

```js
var beforeUnload = null;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'onbeforeunload', {
    get: function () { return beforeUnload; },
    set: function (value) { beforeUnload = value; }
});

(function() {
'use strict';
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return true;
};
console.log(window.onbeforeunload);
console.log(typeof window.onbeforeunload);
})();
```

Comment: Great idea, thanks! I don't get the second part though. Right now the set function just sets it to the value that it is given?

Comment: @J.Doe In the second example the custom setter takes the value and stores it in a variable, which can be returned by the getter function. Basically it replaces the default getters and setters, keeping the function from ever truly being registered as a beforeunload handler, while still making it look like it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the set function so that it is always null.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'onbeforeunload', {
  set: v => {
    return null;
  }
});
```